# Markdown: Links to markdown files in nested directories

Tags: markdown, bitbucket, wiki

I created a Bitbucket wiki.

And I find an issue: how to make links to pages in nested folders?

I have a structure:

- `one.md`
- `two.md`
- `dir1/`

  - `three.md`
- `dir2/`

  - `four.md`

If I want to add on home wiki pages one or two, I will use

```
[[one]]  
[[two]]
```

But if I write something similar for other pages...

```
[[dir1/three]]  
[[dir2/four]]
```

nothing seems to be ok.

What is the correct symbol that separate folders in path to file?

What is the correct way for nested directories in markdown wiki?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bitbucket doesn't recognize links of this type using the `[[` ... `]]` syntax. However, the full link syntax `[link text](path/to/target)` seems to work fine:

```
[three](dir1/three)
[four](dir2/four)
```

Comment: does this still work? I get a 404 following your answer.

Comment: Due to this bug: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6315/relative-urls-in-readmemd-files-only-work it does not work in the README.md but it works in the source folders, also for the README.md

Comment: From your Dashboard, you can use `[one](../../wiki/One)` to link to your wiki pages

Comment: this is mostly useless because link includes commit hash and not the branch

Comment: @markokraljevic, the links shown here are all relative.

Comment: click on generated link and bitbucket will generate url with hash and not branch name like gitlab or github which is awful

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following answer will help others?

I found that it also simple to create the structure as you go along by doing the following:

1. add something like  `a list of [[Wiki/Notes.md|notes]]`
2. add `== Table of contents ==`
3. and add `<<toc Wiki/ >>` to generate the automatic table.

You have to use `Creole` markup for this to work.

When you now save and click on the link, you have a option to create the file automatically.

To get from the Readme.md file to the wiki use something like:

```
documented in the [Wiki](../../wiki/Home)
```

and to get from the wiki to the repository:

```
The files are all in the [[../src/|repository]].
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Wiki now supports cross-links such as `[[Page1]]`

Note that the links are case-sensitive.